Office.Interop.Excel & Office.Interop.Outlook Click Once Deployment & Windows 11
I have a web application developed in work. Thankfully it all runs flawlessly under a Windows 10 environment and has done unaided for the last two years. The web application is installed in an intranet environment MS Server 2016 R2. The application supports a click once deployment application which incorporates both excel and outlook interop libraries. Now I have recently installed the above application as installed on our server at work on a Windows 11 computer at home. Now the roll out on the Windows 11 computer is identical to our Windows 10 environment at work.
The situation I have is occasionally the interop libraries for both excel and outlook can report to be deregistered on the Windows 11 computer. Something that has never happened in work on the Windows 10 computers. Essentially I am future proofing the application at the moment for when we roll out of Windows 11 at work. This automatic deregistering appears to be an intermittent problem on the Windows 11 computer and can happen randomly every few weeks unannounced.
The fix for this is removing an additional empty key from the registry when either the excel or outlook interop libraries report to be deregistered. The solution to fixing the above I have found is as follows:
You launch regedit you locate the TypeLib key under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
from the TypeLib section you search depending which interop reports to be deregistered either office.interop.excel or office.interop.outlook. Lets assume its the excel interop reports to be deregistered. you search for office.interop.excel. This will bring you to the where the office.interop.excel is registered in the registry. Now typically if excel reports to be deregistered you will notice two keys in the office.interop.excel section.
The first key is 1.7 which typically has a value for office.interop.excel library now the second mysterious key that appears just below that is 1.9 in my registry when I select that key to have a look at what values are assigned to it. Its always empty. The solution I have found is to delete the 1.9 key and all works perfectly again. The office.Interop.excel work as normal on the computer again. The exact same process as described above for the excel interop applies to the office.interop.outlook as well you delete the extra empty key. Typically when this happens for outlook there is typically an extra empty key added to the registry on my machine this key is usually 1.9. Deleting this empty key resolves the problem for outlook as well.
Curious to know why this happens. I have googled this with very little help available. I could be wrong to say this. But it could be a matter of setting the embed interop type to true in Visual Studio in my case this is false. I don't want to break this for Windows 10 and fix it for Windows 11. Any help or guidance much appreciated.
